# How to use foreach loop inside a foreach in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching data from the database and showing in the table like this.

```
        <?php foreach($blogs->result() as $blog): ?>
            <td><?php echo $blog->title;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $blog->description;?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I want to show the drop-down from another table so how can i achieve that?

```
        <?php foreach($blogs->result() as $blog): ?>
            <td><?php echo $blog->title;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $blog->description;?></td>
            <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="orderStatus" id="orderId" class="form-control">
                        <option value="<?php echo $name['user_id']; ?>"><?php  echo $name['user_name'];?></option>
                    </select>   
            </div>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create selectbox options string first. in this case, it is `$optionsString`, and suppose that `$optionsList` contains all the values you want to add to the selectbox

```
<?php
$optionsString = "";
foreach ($optionsList as $option) {
    $optionsString .= "<option value=" . $option['user_id'] . ">" . 
      $option['user_name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

next add this `$optionsString` to the HTML part of the snippet you provided in your question:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="orderStatus" id="orderId" class="form-control">
        <?php echo $optionsString; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Placing `<option value=...` _inside_ an `<option`? Just echo the `$optionsString`

Comment: @brombeer yeah, that's right